# How to debug tests within Symfony 4 and Simple-PHPUnit?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

In earlier versions, it was possible to debug any unit test within functionality provided by PHPStorm. How should I run debug session on a particular test using `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit`?

Comment: I run it the same way (locally), just changed "path to phpunit.phar" in `Setings -> Languages & frameworks -> PHP -> Test frameworks` to simple-phpunit

Comment: @NikitaU. — but PHPstorm screamed that phpunit couldn't be found. However, I noticed that phpunit has been installed in hidden (``.phpunit``) directory inside ``vendor``.

Comment: Unfortunately, ``simple-phpunit`` starts an another sub-process so debugging is weird. Still working on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit hidden right now.

1. Run `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit` to fetch some not-so-visible dependencies,
2. Setup a new test framework within PHPStorm using this path: `/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-5.7/phpunit` with `path to composer.phar` checked. Keep in mind not to forget specifying `phpunit.xml` as default configuration to provide autoloaders,
3. All now works.